# Differentiating various styles of writing conditional statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't understand why some codes in Python are written with no indentation.

Both functions do the same thing but why the first function which is  is_leap1 are writting in style with return only and no if statemnt? How did the first function return True and False without using if and else: ?

```
def is_leap1(year):
    return year % 4==0and(year %100 !=0 or year %400==0)

print(is_leap1(2014))

def is_leap2(year):
    if (( year%400 == 0)or (( year%4 == 0 ) and ( year%100 != 0))):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_leap2(2014))
```

output

```
False
False
```

Comment: Comparison operators such as `==`, `!=`,  `<`, `>=`, `and`, `or`, etc, all return Boolean values naturally.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: Think about it: why would you write `if true_or_false: return True; else: return False` rather than just `return true_or_false`?

Comment: Thank you guys, I get it now. so what about when you get a code with 

xx for x in list

why don't you just write it with indentation as

for x in list:
     xx

Comment: I think you're trying to describe a *list comprehension*. You do it because it's more efficient than repeatedly appending.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
I am refering to different ways of writing a syntax. is there a reference that describe different ways of writing the syntax ? particularly when indentation is not used?

Comment: Not really, because what you're trying to describe is multiple different things. I'd recommend going through a structured tutorial that introduces and explains these ideas; see https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F. Once you understand the expression, you'll see that the two are equivalent, as are `return True if expr else False` and `return expr or False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison operators such as `==`, `!=`,  `<`, `>=`, `and`, `or`, etc, all return Boolean values naturally. Therefore, you do not need to use `if` statements to return `True` or `False` when using these operators. You can test this trivially yourself:

```
print(5 > 3)                     # True
print(True if 5 > 3 else False)  # True
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) makes this explicit:

> Comparisons yield boolean values: `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first function Logical operators are used which output True or False.

Since the condition *year % 4==0* **and** (*year %100 !=0* **or** *year %400==0*) is written using Logical AND, OR, these functions will compute the value and produce the value True or False, which is then finally returned using the **return** keyword from the function